# Запрос. Кол-во переходов в год

Tags: python, matplotlib

Всем доброго времени суток. Имеется БД со столбцами id, date, value.
id - id человека, может повторятся.
date - год записи.
value - например это цифры 0 или 3.

При каждой записи в бд, человеку назначается value, которое может поменяться (совершить переход) в последствие (в следующем году). Значение может увеличиваться, но не уменьшатся.

Суть задачи. Построить таблицу со столбцами: date, count. Где date - год, а count это поле которое показывает кол-во переходов из какой либо группы в группу 3.

В каком направление мыслить? Задача не привязана к какой либо ДБ, просто нужен сам алгоритм того, как это сделать.
Если поможет, то работаю на pandas.
Пробовал вариант с группировкой по дате и кол-ву записей, у которых значение меньше 3. И второй группой у которых значение равное 3. После вычитал значение и получалась какая-то ерунда...

Comment: приведите пример исходных данных, и то что необходимо получить в результате

Comment: *Построить таблицу* — это обязательное условие? может быть хватит *view* или просто результата запроса *select*?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы имеете в виду алгоритм без привязки к БД, то я бы создал триггер, который изменял бы значение count каждый раз, когда изменялось бы значение value у какого-либо человека.